# Google+ Sign-In Error: Invalid_client

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-signin

I'm working with this google API SDK for PHP. When I click on the sign-in button google displays the following error:

[image]

I searched around the web and found some possible sulutions to my problem that could be related to:

-WEB ORIGIN
-REDIRECT URI

The problem is that I don't understand the porpouse of this two fields, so if they are related to this error, how can I find what to put into the "WEB ORIGIN" and into the "REDIRECT URI"???

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Redirect URI is where user goes after she consents the access your app is asking for (if this page does not have any error, it will prompt user to allow permission).

User is redirected from google after consent to your specified URI so that your web app can handle the rest of the flow. This URI also has to match with what you set on the api console to prevent some malicious code wanting to redirect user to another URI.

The web origin field aims to ensure that the javascript code served to user comes from your (legit) website. Otherwise other people can pretend to be your app and ask users for information too. So the value entered into the console just has to match with the domain of your web server that client receives the script from.

Answer (score 1):

this error indicates that the clientID you are using is invalid, Google can not found the client you provide. I suggest you check the client ID again.

-WEB ORIGIN -REDIRECT URI 
these two parameters are not the cause of this error. If the redirect uri is not correct, the error is "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" and WEB ORIGIN specify the URL of your backend API.